# How to fix "protocol wrongtype for socket" in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have installed `anaconda3` with `python 3.x` in windows 7 professional 64 bit processor.
While opening new jupyter notebook in `python 3 kernel`. It shows error message as

> "Assertion failed :protocol wrong type for socket [10041 ]
>   c:\ci\zeromq_1549025594292\work\src\ip.cpp:417"

and python stopped running. 
Kindly help to fix the issue.

Regards,
Geetha S

expect the new notebook to be opened for coding

Comment: Having the same problem. Did you solve this issue yet?

Answer (score 1):

finally solved this one using 2 alternative methods:

1. go to[repo archive](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/) and download `anaconda3 5.3.1` from Nov 2018 (This is the earliest version with python 3.7). This helped my issues, by matching up versions of `python` and `jupyter` etc. [as an aside, if you are using the archive to download older versions, the below link tells you the version of python running with that particular version of anaconda [link](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/oldpkglists/)]
2. A work around is to download the latest version you can and create a new environment with either `python 3.5` or `3.6` as explained above. To do this:

-in anaconda prompt type either:

"conda create -n py35 python=3.5 anaconda" or

"conda create -n py36 python=3.6 anaconda".

This takes a while but at the end you will be asked to type something like:

> "conda activate py36" to activate the new environment.

to make sure it is activated type:

"conda info --envs".

In the environments list that displays, the active environment is highlighted with an asterisk (*).
That should work, but just to be safe, go to anaconda navigator and then environments on the left hand side. left click on the `"play button"` and `"open with jupyter notebook"`

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem (also on Windows 7), and managed to get it working. As the answers here seemed rather unspecific I thought I would record the steps I took.

Essentially I didn't figure out what was going wrong, but I just tried different versions until it worked. My baseline miniconda3 was 64-bit, though I don't think that matters, as I created a second, non-base environment to run in. Regardless, my miniconda3 installer was

```
Miniconda3-latest-Windows-x86_64.exe 2020-03-11 10:38:26    20d6bd9b3bd62f1fd874315b6b38c159
```

Also, the other answers say to install anaconda, which takes a long time and a lot of disk space. I just used miniconda, which is smaller, quicker to install, and you can download the same packages as you find you need them.

My steps were

1. Create new python 3.6 environment
2. Install jupyter in the new environment
3. Downgrade the version of zeromq in the environment.
4. I also installed numpy, which I needed for the notebooks I was using.

Here are the commands I used:

```
conda create --name python36 python=3.6
conda activate python36
conda install zeromq=4.2.2
conda install numpy
```

Here are the package versions I ended up with (I left out some that I thought were unimportant):

```
ipykernel                 5.1.4            py36h39e3cac_0
ipython                   7.13.0           py36h5ca1d4c_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py36_0
ipywidgets                7.5.1                      py_0
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py36_7
jupyter_client            6.1.3                      py_0
jupyter_console           6.1.0                      py_0
jupyter_core              4.6.3                    py36_0
libsodium                 1.0.16               h9d3ae62_0
matplotlib                3.1.3                    py36_0
matplotlib-base           3.1.3            py36h64f37c6_0
mkl                       2020.1                      216
mkl-service               2.3.0            py36hb782905_0
mkl_fft                   1.0.15           py36h14836fe_0
mkl_random                1.1.1            py36h47e9c7a_0
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1
notebook                  6.0.3                    py36_0
numpy                     1.18.1           py36h93ca92e_0
numpy-base                1.18.1           py36hc3f5095_1
prompt-toolkit            3.0.5                      py_0
prompt_toolkit            3.0.5                         0
python                    3.6.10               h9f7ef89_2
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0
pywin32                   227              py36he774522_1
pywinpty                  0.5.7                    py36_0
pyzmq                     17.0.0           py36hfa6e2cd_0
qt                        5.9.7            vc14h73c81de_0
sqlite                    3.31.1               h2a8f88b_1
terminado                 0.8.3                    py36_0
testpath                  0.4.4                      py_0
tornado                   6.0.4            py36he774522_1
winpty                    0.4.3                         4
zeromq                    4.2.2                h7a7be3a_2
```

To start jupyter I created a .bat file:

```
set conda_root=C:\Users\username\miniconda3
set work_root=D:\projects\EdX

d:
cd %work_root%

call %conda_root%\Scripts\activate.bat python36

call jupyter notebook

echo Jupyter server stopped

pause
```

(The `work_root` folder is where my .ipynb files are located.)

The `pause` command is there to keep the cmd.exe window open so you can read any messages or errors jupyter logs there, but you do have to close the window manually each time you stop the server.

I do get a deprecation warning in my Anaconda Prompt cmd.exe window:

```
C:\Users\username\miniconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py:19: 
    VisibleDeprecationWarning: zmq.eventloop.minitornado is deprecated in pyzmq 14.0 and will be removed.
    Install tornado itself to use zmq with the tornado IOLoop.
```

but at this point I don't care.

Answer (score 0):

I think my answer may be little bit late
This error come form the python version which is installed in your PC is older than the version inside jupyter notebook
to fix this u can downgrade your version through conda command or
just creata a new enviroment:
conda create -n py35 python=3.5 anaconda 
remember change your own version